# Flutter: Is it possible to do RTSP (or RTMP) streaming with about 30 sec late and allow users to navigate back like Youtube Streaming?

Tags: flutter, video-streaming, rtsp, rtmp, live-streaming

I am developing a Flutter application; a digital scoreboard for billiard and want to add some video streaming feature to it.

I was able to do live streaming with vlc player package and IP camera that supports RTSP streaming, but the problem is I want it to stream like 30 seconds late as players would want to check if the ball did hit or not after they play. Also, players may want to playback 30 secs ago again to check the previous situation.

So basically what I want to implement is delayed streaming with playback feature just like Youtube or Twitch's live streaming feature. It seems not easy as I imagined first since I have to record and play the streaming at the same time..

Is it avaialable in Flutter? or if so how should I search for this feature? Is there a term for this kinda streaming? I'll appreciate any help..
Thank you for your time!

I tried to flutter_vlc_player package but I was only successful with live streaming.

I am also working on ffmpeg but I am not sure if it is fully available for this feature in Flutter..

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this scenario, you just need to do some special handling on the player. An easier solution is to use the HLS protocol, as it is based on segmented files, and you can set the duration of each segment to 30 seconds.

Assuming you are using SRS, refer to [SRS HLS](https://ossrs.io/lts/en-us/docs/v5/doc/hls), and configure as follows:

```
vhost __defaultVhost__ {
    hls {
        enabled on;
        hls_fragment 30;
        hls_window 180;
    }
}
```

The generated HLS files may like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:32
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:30.240, no desc
livestream-0.ts
#EXTINF:30.600, no desc
livestream-1.ts
#EXTINF:31.400, no desc
```

This way, when the player is playing, it will get 30-second segments, and you just need to allow dragging within the current segment on the player. Of course, you may need to find a player that can implement this feature, or modifying based on hls.js is also possible.